# Limpar com um comando o conteúdo do IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, idle-ide

Eu estou criando um *database* que gere tabelas, mas para a parte gráfica não estou usando qualquer livraria particular, como TkInter, mas só o IDLE e alguns *prompts*.

Mas gostaria de melhorar a parte do menu do database. Um problema é que quando escolho uma opção, e essa é executada, depois o *prompt* é mostrado outra vez, porque uso um *while loop*, que só acaba quando o utente clica o numero 6. É possível, por exemplo, apagar o menu anterior antes de mostrar o novo?

Esta é a situação:

[image: SS]

Comment: Você tentou limpar a tela do IDLE antes de reexibir o menu? Algo como: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432480/any-way-to-clear-pythons-idle-window ou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517970/how-to-clear-python-interpreter-console

Comment: Bom, dá de tentar [essa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12491227/2896619) e [essa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/517992/2896619) soluções também (lá dos mesmos links). A segunda é um hack bem simples muito bem votado (que imprime um grande número de *line feeds* e faz *parecer* que a tela ficou limpa).

Comment: Se funcionar (ou te satisfizer), não esqueça de postar você mesmo uma resposta aqui (claro, citando a fonte lá do SOen). :)

Answer (score 2):

A reposta a esta pergunta é **não**, não se pode cancelar com um comando de Python o conteúdo da shell interativa ou IDLE, como se pode fazer em *Bash* com o comando *clear*. Existe porém pelo menos 2 soluções alternativas:

1. Usar um loop que itera por um tot de vezes (por exemplo 100) fazendo um print duma linha vazia, simulando assim que o *IDLE* está a ser limpo. O seguinte pode ser um exemplo do simples código:

   ```
   def clear(times=100):
       """simulates the cleanning of the IDLE"""
       if isinstance(times, int):
           for i in range(times):
               print()
   ```

   O problema desta solução é que a chamada ao `print()` requer uma grande quantidade de recursos, e demora bastante a ser limpa a tela, e não penso seja uma grande solução.
2. Fazer partir o program a partir do *terminal*, usufruindo assim do comando *Bash* ***clear***. Neste caso, o programa funciona muito mais suavemente, mas depende sempre dum terminal.

Se sabem doutras soluções, não hesitem a propor ;)